# List files and folders in current dir with special handling for tty

Tags: beginner, file-system, rust

I want to write a custom `ls` command to learn rust.

This is what I've done as for the version 1.0. This display files and folders in a cyan or white if it's on a TTY. Otherwise I just print them.

I'm using `atty` and `crossterm` crates.

**What I want reviewed**

- Is there a better way to deal with `OsStr`?
- Is there a better way to convert `OsStr` to print-able strings?
- Is there a better way to handle errors?
- Any other area is fair game too.
- Is my enum use good?

---

```
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};
use std::path::Path;

use atty::Stream;
use crossterm::{Color, Colored};

enum FileEntryType {
    File,
    Dir,
}


fn main() {
    // WHY: no need to print colours on non tty
    if atty::is(Stream::Stdout) {
        visit_location(Path::new("."), &color_print);
    } else {
        visit_location(Path::new("."), &normal_print);
    }
}

fn visit_location(dir: &Path, cb: &dyn Fn(FileEntryType, &DirEntry)) {
    if !dir.is_dir() {
        return;
    }

    if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir(dir) {
        for entry in entries {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                let path = entry.path();
                if path.is_dir() {
                    cb(FileEntryType::Dir, &entry);
                } else {
                    cb(FileEntryType::File, &entry);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        println!("Failed to list {}", dir.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap());
    }
}

fn color_print(file_kind: FileEntryType, p: &DirEntry) {
    match file_kind {
        FileEntryType::File => println!("{}{}", Colored::Fg(Color::White), p.file_name().as_os_str().to_str().unwrap()),
        FileEntryType::Dir => println!("{}{}", Colored::Fg(Color::Cyan), p.file_name().as_os_str().to_str().unwrap())
    }
}

fn normal_print(_: FileEntryType, p: &DirEntry) {
    println!("{}", p.file_name().as_os_str().to_str().unwrap());
}
```

How it looks like

[image: Screenshot of terminal output]

Answer (score 4):

**`OsStr` conversion**

According to the [`path` source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#1848-1850), `s.as_os_str().to_str()` is the same as `s.to_str()`:

```
pub fn as_os_str(&self) -> &OsStr {
    &self.inner
}

pub fn to_str(&self) -> Option<&str> {
    self.inner.to_str()
}
```

Moreover, using `unwrap()` here is not safe at all as invalid Unicode is pretty common (e.g. when mounting file system with alien character encoding). There is [`Path::to_string_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_string_lossy) that converts path to a printable string.

---

**Using `crossterm`**

`crossterm` provides helper macros to output strings. It is more idiomatic to use them instead of `println!("{}{}", ...)`: [`execute`](https://docs.rs/crossterm/0.12.0/crossterm/macro.execute.html) and [`queue`](https://docs.rs/crossterm/0.12.0/crossterm/macro.queue.html).

Using `queue` may be beneficial in case of outputting to the pipe instead of stdout.

---

**Reporting errors**

It is common practice to report errors to `stderr`. It also may be more helpful to show error reason when `fs::read_dir()` fails. You can also use `crossterm` to make it more colorful:

```
match fs::read_dir(dir) {
    Err(err) =>
        execute!(
            stdout(),
            Colored::Fg(Color::Red),
            Output(format!("Failed to list {}: {}", dir.to_string_lossy(), err)),
            Reset),
    Ok(entries) => ..
}
```

---

**Callbacks**

Using callbacks to print colorful vs. normal is a nice idea, but is not future-proof. It will be hard to add other output options like short/long view, hidden files, etc.

Comment: Good catch on the crossterm macro. Very informative.